# Cómo estructurar correctamente el contenido de este diseño web utilizando Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual debo maquetar correctamente el diseño del contenido web según el prototipo(imagen) que me dieron. Actualmente tengo un problema y es que no se como realizarlo de forma adecuada utilizando Bootstrap 5, no sé si es más conveniente hacerlo con Grid o Flex del mismo Bootstrap. Por ejemplo este es lo que llevo pero no logro el espaciado (lineas rojas) que se puede observar en el prototipo.

[image: Imagen del prototipo deseado]

Esto es lo que llevo actualmente.

[image: Mi avance actual]

Y mi código:

```css
.input-group-price{
    background-color: var(--gris-4-f4f4f4);
    padding: 0  20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--gris-1-textos)
}

.input-price{
    border-left: none;
}

.text-form{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="financial-section">
    <div class="row pb-3">
      <h2 class="title">Estado situación financiera</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row row-cols-2">
        <div class="d-flex align-content-center">
          <div class="flex-grow-1">
            <label class="form-label text-form"><span>*</span>Activo Corriente</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text input-group-price">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-price" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="flex-grow-1">
            <label class="form-label text-form"><span>*</span>Activo Corriente</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text input-group-price">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-price" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Aunque aún me falta el resto de los campos del formulario, mi propósito es tener los primeros dos exactamente iguales al prototipo para que sólo sea repetir la misma estructura para los demás campo y guiarme de una estructura correcta para el resto del diseño.

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Bootstrap se adapta a las distintas resoluciones a través de su grid y en un sitio lo verás de un modo y en otro pues quizás un poco desplazado del otro, pero es por ser lo más responsive posible supongo... si quieres algo realmente estático deberás forzarlo con atributos style en los elementos o bien agregando <style></style> o bien tu propia hoja CSS en el header después de la de bootstrap con sus clases que apliques a los elementos que ahora te la están jugando, pero yo no lo haria, la verdad, porque cuando cambien la resolución quizas queda mal al estar tan forzado.

Comment: Por cierto, usa la clase `text-nowrap` en los label para que se parezca algo más a lo que quieres